# Is 2-methyl propyl and 2-methyl propane the same?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm very sorry if this is a very simple question but it has been bugging me for a while Google searches for both 2-methyl propyl and 2-methyl propane give me the same structure .

My Intuition says propyl is the write one since it looses a hydrogen ,is there a very terrible flaw in my reasoning ?

Comment: 2-Methyl propyl is the equivalent of 2-adjective-adjective looking for a noun to modify. 2-methylpropane is = to 2-adjective-noun, which is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not the same. 2-methyl propyl is a substituent group. 2-methyl propane is a molecule.

2-methylpropyl methanoate would be an example of a molecule with the methylpropyl substituent. Also known as isobutyl formate.

[image: 2-methylpropyl methanoate]

Comment: It would probably a good idea to show the difference; the question itself is not a stellar fit for our site.